# sed parsing data: fields (words) separated with whitespace

Tags: sed

I'm using `sed` on Linux, trying to match data lines having three fields, tab separated (but the separation could be any whitespace), as in:

```
 12.3 0a 1b
 15.5 0v 1h
 17.7 5k 3c
```

; right now I'm using this:

```
sed -n 's/^\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)/\1\t\3\t\2/p' mydata.txt
```

... so I'm able to extract and manipulate (in the example, just position inversion) individual fields via `\1`, `\2`, `\3`.

Is there a better way to specify this?

Cheers!

Comment: `sed` may not be the best tool for this. Is ther a particular reason you don't want to use `awk`, or `perl` or something better suited?

Comment: Hi @dmckee - usually, I'm not that well acquainted with `awk` or `perl`, so whenever I have a "field inversion in text data" problem like this, the first thing I think of is what I know: "`\2 \1`" which is something I get from `sed`. However, `sed` not being suited for the task is also an answer I appreciate (_since as I said, that's not the first thing that pops to my mind when I have this problem_)... Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trivial example in awk to suggest what can be done

```
awk '{print $2 $1 $3}` < input_file.txt
```

simply rearranges the first two fields while printing all three on all lines.

To rearrange those lines have exactly three fields, preserve any that start with `#` (i.e. comment in sh-like languages) and delete all others

```
awk `/^#/{print $0;next} NF==3{print $2 $1 $3;next} {}' < input_file.txt
```

Most unix systems have a fairly complete awk man-page.

The important this for your purposes here is that the fields are accessibly with `$1`, `$2`, ..., where "field" is defined as strings of stuff separated by FS (i.e. the field separator) which defaults to  (a space).

Comment: Many thanks for that, @dmckee - `awk` indeed seems better for the job; cheers!